# Laravel - Authentication redirect to page with a 302 found code

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-authorization

I'm doing the authentication and the page after login redirect the specific page but with a 302 found code. And stay at login page.
Why this happens?

```

```
if ($validator->passes()){
    $auth = DB::table('us')->where('username', '=', Input::get('username'))
      ->where('password', '=', Input::get('password'))->get()->first();
    // Try to log the user in.
    if ($auth){
        // Redirect to homepage
        //Auth::login($auth);
        Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password], $remember);
        return Redirect::to('app/dashboard');
    }
  }
  else{
    return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validator);
  }
```

```

Thanks

Comment: 302 found is a return code used to tell browsers that a redirect is happening, and usually includes some sort of packet to tell browsers what page to redirect to. You should be getting a 200 OK code when it is redirecting successfully

Comment: so why this is not redirect well? @Sub6Resources

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with lavarel to help you figure out the problem. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function SignIn(Request $request)
{

      $this->validate($request,[
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
      ]);    
    if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request['email'],'password'=>$request['password']])){
        return redirect('app/dashboard');
}
      return redirect()->back();
}
```

This works fine for me in Laravel 5.2. and make sure you imported these in your controller.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

In my `route.php` I have following,

```
Route::post('login',[
            'uses'=>'UserController@SignIn',
              'as'=>'login'
]);
```

Comment: Do you put this code into LoginController? In routes you don't need to add a post to /login? @Sachith

Comment: @user3242861 I just added all the things I have in `route.php` and in my user controller.